# how to add an alert to my "delete all" and "save" button in my view controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

i have added button in my viewController programmatically, i want to add an alert when tapping the button that will appear the alert and remove all the added items in my TableViewCell. how can i do that? and also the save button when the button is tapped the alert for save button will appear.
thank you.

```
class IncallPantryCheckViewController {

let deleteAllButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Delete All", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20.0)!
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: UIControlState.normal)
        return button
    }()
  

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        inCallTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PantryCheckInCallTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PantryCheckInCallTableViewCell")
        
view.addSubview(deleteAllButton)
view.addSubview(saveButton)

deleteAllButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
deleteAllButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
deleteAllButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true
        
saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
saveButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
saveButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -45).isActive = true
    



 }
}
```

Comment: Do you want an alert as a popup? Basically a popup with a message like "are you sure you want to delete all?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're going for the iOS provided alert:

1. Create functions to show delete alert and to actually perform the delete:

   ```
    @objc func tappedDelete() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you sure you want to delete?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
            self.performDelete()
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        // present alert, pick one depending if you're using a navigation controller or not.
        //    self.navigationController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func performDelete() {
        print("Do your delete logic here")
    }
   ```
2. add target action to your button:

   ```
    deleteAllButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedDelete), for: .touchUpInside)
   ```

Repeat above for your save button.